# WCF service host cannot find any service metadata error

Tags: wcf

I keep getting this error when trying to launch my web service in localhost:

> WCF service host cannot find any service metadata

This is the app config file:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
    <add key="SrvName" value="..."/>
    <add key="DbName" value="..."/>
    <add key="DbId" value=".."/>
    <add key="DbPw" value=".."/>
    <add key="userId" value=".."/>
    <add key="userPw" value=".."/>
    <add key="code_rep" value=".."/>
    <add key="tex_rep" value=""/>
    <add key="F_LOG" value="logCla.txt"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="simplecalculmexcomport">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="simplecalculmexcomport" name="WcfsaveRepES.service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            name="simplecalculhttpservice" contract="WcfsaveRepES.Iservice" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            name="simplecalculmexpservice" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any solution?
Thanks

Comment: Does the namespace-qualified class name and the service contract it implements match exactly what you have on your WCF configuration (WcfsaveRepES.service and WcfsaveRepES.Iservice)?

Comment: yes they match exactly, i have already checked that

Comment: You said app.config, but I think you meant web.config.  I see that you don't have any bindings or services in your config.  How did you get this config?  Was it generated by VStudio?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in a `Console` application by adding your configuration to my `Appconfig` file. It works properly.
**Server-side**(`Console` application, Namespace is `ConsoleApp4`).

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(host.Description.Endpoints[0].Address);

            Console.ReadLine();
            host.Close();
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract(Namespace ="ABCD")]

    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]

        string GetData(int value);

    }
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
```

**App.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="simplecalculmexcomport">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="simplecalculmexcomport" name="ConsoleApp4.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            name="simplecalculhttpservice" contract="ConsoleApp4.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            name="simplecalculmexpservice" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9099/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The service can run properly.
What is your project type? After I searched the related errors on the internet, the error seems to mainly refer to a qualified namespace issue(Name property of the service, Contract property of the endpoint section). please refer to the below threads.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff01e402-3ed4-4cf1-bbbc-2ac22af7fc96/wcf-service-host-cannot-find-any-service-metadata?forum=wcf
[Trying to self-host, I get error - wcf service host cannot find any service metadata .. please check if metadata is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970995/trying-to-self-host-i-get-error-wcf-service-host-cannot-find-any-service-meta)
[WCF service host cannot find any service metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221692/wcf-service-host-cannot-find-any-service-metadata)
Please post the complete code, I will try my best to reproduce your issue. Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.